# how to extract links and handle the page as it is loading again and again using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

tring to extract links and want to handle loading. but not the links even.
code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.indiabusinessguide.in/business-categories/agriculture/agricultural-equipment.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('a',class_='link_orange')

for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

please help me to handle this loading and extraction of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the lxml library. Response is received by posting a request to the url using Requests.

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html

contact_list = []
def scrape(url, pages):

  for page in range(1, pages):
    headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=2q0tk3fi1kid0gbdfboh94ed56",
    }

    data = {
      "page": f"{page}"
    }

    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

    links= tree.xpath('//a[@class="link_orange"]')
    for link in links:
      # print(link.get('href'))
      contact_list.append(link.get('href'))


url = "http://www.indiabusinessguide.in/ajax_advertiselist.php"

scrape(url, 10)
print(contact_list)
print(len(contact_list))
```

Comment: the above method does not require to open a browser to get the info. Updated answer with results included. Is that what you want?

Comment: i use my link in your code it is working , thanks but i am getting only first 25 links not all links which appears after we scroll down and page loads. please give me some solution to handle this.

Comment: i got the links from your code and url is working , please tell me how do i get all links upto end of page.

Comment: the link you use in url and the headers you use, from where did you get that information

Comment: go to chrome developer tool and inspect the network tab, under XHR you will find something like ajax.php. Header infomation you can get it from the request header.

Comment: Changed code under my answer, you can change the number in scrape(url, 10) to choose how many page you want to scrape. Please upvote if you like this answer.